# AngularJS $rootScope loses value unless I use promise (trigger.io AJAX request)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise, trigger.io, angular-promise

So this is quite weird. `$rootScope` is getting set correctly within a function, but then loses its value. I can only keep the value if I use a promise. (!?)

I am using a trigger.io (Forge) AJAX request, and upon success I update `$rootScope.queries`. Within the success block, `$rootScope.queries` is set correctly, as shown by the `alert`.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $q) {
    var retrieveHistory = function() {
        forge.logging.log("Retrieving history");
        // Retrieve the history
        forge.request.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:9000/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            $rootScope.queries = data["queries"];
            alert("queries " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.queries));
          },
          error: function (error) {
          }
        });
    }
    retrieveHistory();
```

At this point though, after `retrieveHistory()` has been called, `$rootScope.queries` is now empty. The view doesn't update and inspecting using the Chrome console shows that it is empty.

Let's say I add a promise to the function, but don't really use the promise for anything.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $q) {
    var retrieveHistory = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        forge.logging.log("Retrieving history");
        // Retrieve the history
        forge.request.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:9000/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            $rootScope.queries = data["queries"];
            alert("queries " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.queries));
          },
          error: function (error) {
            deferred.reject("error " + JSON.stringify(error));
          }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var promise = retrieveHistory();
    promise.then();
```

With this promise, `$rootScope.queries` keeps its value. The view updates and Chrome inspector shows the value is set correctly.

Why is this? I simply don't understand this behavior. Why can't I preserve the value of `$rootScope.queries` in the original code? Why does the promise keep the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, 2 questions.

1. why are you using trigger.ajax over $http pr resource which are angular native services hence are fully aware of angulars diges cycle not the case of external libraries.
2. why are you using rootscope you really shouldn't do that unles you are broadcasrting an event inside a service i know no good reason to polute your rootscope.

How ever your problem is likely to be doe to forge.ajax being outside angular digest so you need to execute.

```
$rootScope.$apply()
```

to let rootscope know there are somechangins he needs to be aware of

Comment: Right ( http://plnkr.co/edit/plrufZXBFYtC5vMZcJ4a?p=preview ), and the promise works because it runs a digest cycle for you.

Comment: 1) I am using forge.request because "Normally, in-page JavaScript is only able to make XMLHttpRequests (XHRs) to the same server as one hosting the current web page." (https://trigger.io/modules/request/current/docs/index.html) Can I use $http ?

Comment: 2) I am using rootScope because I am new to Angular and I don't know how to access the scope of another controller. I understand that this is bad, and I will change this as soon as I can.

Comment: I added `$rootScope.$apply()` after the $rootScope update in success. This works in the web, but it doesn't work in ios on trigger.io. If I log a message immediately after $rootScope.$apply(), I see the message on web, but not ios. Why?

Comment: I tried using $http but I get the following error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: i'll have to see the apy probably the problem is that forge is making a request at device level and  $http is making it at webview level hence if the server doesn't support CORS you cant use it right away you need to use the helper method $http.jsonp. As for the scopes just create a controller for your app and use that $scope